# Laravel model deletion hierarchy

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I have 3 models: `Parent`, `Child`, `GrandChild`. Parent `hasMany()` Child, Child `hasMany()` GrandChild. Now when I `->delete()` the Parent model, the Child and GrandChild models remain unaffected. But I also want to delete the related models. I tried doing this in my Controller's `destroy()` method:

```
$parent->childs->grandchilds()->delete();
$parent->childs()->delete();
$parent->delete();
```

but it throws a `BadMethodCallException`, method `grandchilds()` doesn't exist, even though I have a `hasMany()` relationship setup on `Child` Model.

How can I nicely delete all the related models without having to set up foreign key constraints? Because there are more than 3 related models in my application and at this point editing all the migration files will be extremely time-consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you tried it doesn't work because you're calling `->grandchilds()->delete()` on a collection of `childs`, rather than a query builder or a model.

One way would be to foreach over the children:

```
foreach($parent->childs as $child){
    $child->grandchilds()->delete(); // Here you call it on a query builder (relationship)
    $child->delete(); // Here you call it on a model
}
$parent->delete(); // Calling on a model
```

Or you could set up a [`->hasManyThrough(Child, GrandChild)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship and delete like that (also more performant, since you'll only need 3 queries, regardless of the number of children):

```
$parent->grandchilds()->delete(); // Assumed the name of hasManyThrough relationship to be "grandchilds"
$parent->childs()->delete();
$parent->delete();
```

Comment: What if I have to go one level deeper, (or even more at some later point of time) how can I set up hasManyThrough then? Let's say now I have a `GreatGrandChild` model what can I do then?

Comment: There's no nice way of doing it without `on delete cascade`. Foreign keys are your best friend there. It will save you time in the long run and increase performance.

Answer (score 3):

Setup [foreign key constraints with `->onDelete('cascade')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints), for example:

```
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('parents')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Do the same in grandchildren migration.

In this case, when you'll delete parent model, all related children and grandchildren will be [automatically deleted by DB](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/).

Comment: While this is absolutely the way it should be done, asker specifically said >without having to set up foreign key constraints

Comment: @devk I've missed that part. In this case, OP should definitely use the code from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you can't implement cascading deletes as suggested by Alexey, you can use loops to accomplish this:

```
foreach($parent->childs AS $child){
  foreach($child->grandchilds AS $grandchild){
    $grandchild->delete();
  }
  $child->delete();
}
$parent->delete();
```